# JavaScript's "new Audio" not working in conjunction with AWS Cloudfront (CORS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-cloudfront

I've got an AngularJs app that users Pusher (https://pusher.com/) to receive notifications from a back-end service.  Once the notification is received, a short "beep" is played.

The problem is that this beep sound works when I run this code through localhost on my Chrome browser, but does NOT when I visit my AWS CloudFront URL.

Does JavaScript's new Audio(...) work differently when played through AWS CloudFront?

```
        var pusher = null,
            channel = null,
            beep = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/myawsbucket/sounds/beep1.mp3');

        // Firebase Auth's on State Change
        // Register to pusher notification channel when user logs in
        Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function (currentUser) {

            // If desktop version, use pusher to receive notifications
            if (currentUser && !VersioningService.isApp()) {

                if (!pusher) {
                    // register a pusher instance
                    pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_KEY, {
                        "cluster": "us2",
                        "encrypted": true
                    });
                }

                if (!channel) {
                    // register to a pusher channel and listen for notifications
                    console.log("Subscribing to " + currentUser.uid);
                    channel = pusher.subscribe(currentUser.uid);
                    channel.bind('notification', function (data) {
                        // create two copies so you can play it twice back to back
                        var copyOfBeep = beep.cloneNode(),
                            copyOfBeep2 = beep.cloneNode();

                        try {
                            // This makes a sound on my local, but does not when hosted from cloudfront
                            copyOfBeep.play();
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                copyOfBeep2.play();
                            }, 400)
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

** UPDATE **

The problem was the URL passed into new Audio(...).  Even though an error wasn't thrown in the console, it must have been a CORS error.  Changing the URL to the appropriate CloudFront URL did the trick.

** UPDATE 2 **

Looks like Chrome Extensions like disabling HTML5 auto-play will turn off the sounds as well.  Just spent about 3 hours wondering what was going on with that one.  Beware.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: @Aplet123 No, that's part of what's weird.  The code runs fine, just doesn't play any sound when browser is reading from CloudFront.

Comment: Your audio link isn't pointing to CloudFront.  Are you sure you're not getting a CORS error?

Comment: If you just put the audio URL in the address bar, does it play?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot CORS it is!  I changed the URL and it worked.  There just wasn't any error thrown in the console, but I should have given the URL a try.  Dang. 
 Thank you!